# Need help in Android Layout Text in Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem. I have a good looking Layout. So now I want to set a text in the middle of the button. The button includes an image. So how can I change it, that the images have same size and looks good too. I have tried with setting the background but the imagessize change very bad.
Solution please..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/zettelnew"
        android:text="asdsad"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="@style/Button"
        android:layout_height="125dp" 
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/notizzettel" 
        android:text="test"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

style.xml

```
<style name="Button">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You if I undersoot correctly I think you want to show some text below an image in side a button. If you wanto do this I would suggest trying to **setting gravity** of the button in the layout xml,

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

or

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

please note that this has to be done **on the button tag of the layout xml**.

If my understanding was incorrect them I am sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: No I want to use the background function instead of the drawableTop function. But if I use the drawableTop function the layout looks different. Thats the problem. The images are different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Are these images dynamic or static, in other words are you grabbing them from the web or storing them locally.  If they are local images I think the best option is probably just to re-size them manually, so that they are all the same size.

If you can not re-size them manually then I would recommend embedding an imageview inside of the button.  Then you can call the setImageResource(int) or setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm) or setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable).  This will set the image to the forground and then you can use the setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType scaleType) to scale all the images to fit the button.

For more details on those methods check out the Google resource for [imageview](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)

Answer (score 0):

set the gravity to `android:gravity="center"` of the button